# "Ударил" и "вдарил"

Tags: стилистика

Порой встречаю в книжных текстах вместо "ударил" - "вдарил". Литературное ли это слово и, если да, в каких случаях оно употребляется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово *вд**а**рить* является просторечным, а *ударить* - стилистически нейтральное. Синонимы - ударить (нейтр.), вмазать (прост., жаргон.).